# SQL create view with joining 2 table with different criterias

Tags: sql, db2

I would like to create a view to join 2 tables with criteria in respective tables.

```
table 1: 

id  wonum  datetime     type   
---|-----|------------|--------|

1  | 10  | 04/03/2009 | pm     | 

2  | 11  | 04/03/2009 | cm     | 

3  | 12  | 04/03/2009 | pm     | 

4  | 13  | 01/01/2009 | pm     |

table 2: 

wonum    asset   
-------|-------|

10     | A1  | 

10     | A2  | 

11     | A1  | 

12     | A1  | 

12     | A2  | 

12     | A3  | 

13     | A1  |
```

I would like to create a view to group table2, asset field and find latest date in table1 and corresponding fields with the latest date.

Currently I am able to retrieve the records for grouping and latest date with the below SQL,but unable to retrieve corresponding data on table1 such as type and wonum:

```
select asset1,max(datetime)from (
select b.asset as asset1, a.datetime as datetime from table1 a, table2 b
where a.wonum = b.wonum )
group by asset11
```

Currently I am using IBM db2 to create the view. Please kindly advise. Many Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: I don't really knwo DB2, but you have "group by asset11". Try change that to "group by asset1"

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the query by removing the subquery:

```
  select b.asset, max(a.datetime)
  from table1 a join
       table2 b 
       on a.wonum = b.wonum
  group by b.asset;
```

Instead, you an use the `row_number()` function:

```
select ab.*
from (select b.asset, a.*
             row_number() over (partition by b.asset order by a.datetime desc) as seqnum
      from table1 a join
           table2 b 
           on a.wonum = b.wonum
     ) ab
where seqnum = 1;
```

I'm not sure exactly which fields you want, but you should be able to get whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

What about simplifying the query, add the required fields in both the select and the group by:

```
SELECT b.asset as asset1, a.type, a.wonum, max(a.datetime)
FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.wonum = b.wonum
GROUP BY b.asset, a.type, a.wonum
```